# JavaScript, Object with a key value of an image

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to making a RPG game with multiple character so I am making objects for them.

I would like to put an img for each of them.

How do I set a key to an image of the character?

Comment: character.image = new Image() ?

Comment: You want the _key_ to be an image or the _value_ for the key to be an image?

Comment: function young_link = {
 power: 30,
 cpower: 20,
 hp: 3,
 img: I WANT THE IMAGE HERE
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a link to the picture:

```
var character1 ={
  image:'http://url-to-image'
}
```

or you could base 64 encode the image.
Here's a online encoder:https://www.base64-image.de/
then you would use the base64 string as a attribute.

```
var character2 = {
  image: 'super-long-base64-stringbd39bf37fb893whf793whf839...'
}
```

from there you could write a function that could place the img on the screen

```
function(character){
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src=character.image;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

This would just append the image to the body, position and placement would have to be worked it

Comment: so do I do that inside the object?

Comment: oh, i see the image: is the key

Comment: yes, so in this case the key is 'image' and the value will be the url of the image or the base64 encoding

Comment: Yes, if you are using local files you would just reference them with the url method. so if the image was in the same directory as the js file you could just reference it like: {image:'myimage.gif'}

Comment: var young_link = {
 power: 30,
 cpower: 20,
 hp: 3,
 image: "../images/young_link.jpg"
};

Comment: this what I have then I trying to set it to the page with: $("#test").html(young_link.image); and it just putting the ../images/young_link.jpg to the div